# Where can I find a proof of Dupin's Theorem?

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry

I'm trying find a proof of Dupin's Theorem. It claims:

> The surfaces of a triply orthogonal system intersect each other irr lines of curvature. (Three families of surfaces are said to form a triply orthogonal system in an open set $U \subset \mathbb R^3$ if a unique surface of each family passes through each point $p \in U$ and if the three surfaces that pass through $p$ are pairwise orthogonal.)

Thanks for all hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had fined it in these books:
Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces [Manfredo P. do Carmo]
Problem 20 Page 152 Hint 484
Geometric Methods and Applications [Jean Gallier][2ed]
Theorem 20.3. Page 629
Here is a sketch of the proof (from the second book)
 First, we note that if two surfaces $X_1$ and $X_2$ intersect along a curve $C$, and if they form a constant angle along $C$, then the geodesic torsion $\tau^1_g$ of $C$ on $X_1$ is equal to the geodesic torsion $\tau^2_g$ of $C$ on $X_2$. Indeed, if $\theta_1$ is the angle between $N_1$ and $n$, and $\theta_2$ is the angle between $N_2$ and $n$, where $N_1$ is the normal to $X_1$, $N_2$ is the normal to $X_2$, and $n$ is the principal normal vector of $C$, then $$\lambda:=\theta_1−\theta_2,$$ where $\lambda$ is some constant, and thus $$\frac{d\theta_1}{ds}=\frac{d\theta_2}{ds},$$ which shows that $$\tau^1_g=\tau−\frac{d\theta_1}{ds}=\tau−\frac{d\theta_2}{ds}=\tau^2_g.$$ Now, if the system of surfaces is triply orthogonal, letting $τ_{ij}$ be the geodesic torsion of the curve of intersection $C_{ij}$ between $X_i \in F_i$ and $X_j \in F_j$ (where $1\le i<j\le 3$), which is well defined, since $X_i$ and $X_j$ intersect orthogonally, from an easy observation (exercise 19 from the first book) the geodesic torsions of orthogonal curves are opposite, and thus $$\tau_{12}=−\tau_{13}, \tau_{23}=−\tau_{12}, \tau_{13}=−\tau_{23},$$ from which we get that $$\tau_{12}=\tau_{23}=\tau_{13}=0.$$

---

1. Exercise 19: Let $C\subset S$ be a regular curve in $S$. Let $p \in C$ and $\alpha(s)$ be a parametrization of $C$ in $p$ by arc length so that $\alpha(0) = p$. Choose in $T_p(S)$ an orthonormal positive basis $\{t, h\}$, where $t = \alpha'(0)$. The geodesic torsion $\tau_g$,  of $C\subset S$ at p is defined by $$\tau_g=\left\langle\frac{dN}{ds}(0),h\right\rangle$$
   Prove that
   a) $\tau_g = (k_1 - k_2) \cos(\phi)\sin(\phi)$, where $\phi$ is the angle from $e_1$ to $t$ and $t$ is the unit tangent vector corresponding to the principal curvature $k_1$.